# Why do Metro/Modern UI videos and games crash on Windows Server 2012 with Desktop Experience feature installed?

Tags: video, windows-8, modern-ui, windows-server-2012, gaming

I am using Windows Server 2012 as a desktop OS and but videos and Metro games from Windows Store keep crashing.

- Where can I see error logs of what goes wrong?
- How can I fix my problem?

**Update**

I found someone reporting a similar problem here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-winapps/video-app-stops-working/f98f7475-9e4b-402d-bb5f-808d063ff37d

**Partial Solution**

This fixed the video problem for me:
http://www.neowin.net/news/how-to-install-legacy-intel-hd-graphics-drivers-on-windows-8

(There is also an NVIDIA card but have no idea how to tell the Modern UI to make use of it - *thanks* be to Nvidia Optimus)

**Complete Solution**

Some DLLs are just missing on Server 2012: http://www.win2012workstation.com/xinput-and-xaudio-dlls/. Now all games run and videos and music play smoothly :D!

Comment: What video card is installed? This happened all the time on my laptop with nVidia, until I updated to the very latest drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following suggestions:

1. Run `sfc /scannow` in a Administrative Command Prompt.
2. Uninstall and reinstall the apps that don't work.
3. Update all your drivers (esp. graphics drivers).
4. Compile this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Metro-style-DirectX-18f98448) and check if it works.

You can use the Event Viewer to view the error logs.

Comment: Thanks but it is now doing a system-wide verification. How is that related?

Comment: **can** yes :) but the system is brand new. Will give event viewer a try now.

Comment: Both Adera and Videos seem to throw file not found exceptions but cannot see from the event viewer which files they look for o_O. I get the feeling this might take me a looong time to figure out perhaps even until somebody else with more Windows experience run into a similar issue and reports his fixes.

Comment: `sfc /scannow` did not find any integrity problems.

Comment: Weather, News, Mail, Skype all work; anything except games and videos.

Comment: @Just finished with 2 and 3. Nothing has changed. If I could dig deeper into event viewer logs or see them at increased detail, that would be quite helpful. Perhaps I can compile a Metro app sample with VS2012 and see what is going wrong with video and 3d games.

Comment: I found someone having a similar problem and narrowing it down to a display driver issue. Don't know how to fix it in my case yet though.

Comment: See, I told you it was related to the driver. Try downloading the latest `beta` drivers. What graphics card do you have?